# Did Kes become a Traveler?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In the Voyager episode "The Gift," we see Kes become so powerfully psychic that she leaves the corporeal realm of existence. [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kes) states this about her departure from our galaxy in general and Voyager in particular:

> Kes began to undergo a massive surge in her mental powers. [...] Kes became telekinetic and was able to carry out delicate surgical procedures using only her mind. Unfortunately, she rapidly started to destabilize at the subatomic level and was causing massive damage to Voyager as a result. Taking a shuttle, she left the ship to explore her new condition and, **as she left the corporeal world behind**, pushed Voyager out of Borg space, 9,500 light years closer to Earth, as a parting gift. (emph. mine)

Something that she said during the episode caught my attention:

> KES: I don't know, and that's what makes it all so exciting. **It's as
> if I can see into a place where the distinction between matter and
> energy and thought no longer exists.** (emphasis mine)

To me, that sounds an awful lot like this:

> WESLEY: Is Mister Kosinski like he sounds? A joke?
>
> TRAVELLER: No, that's too cruel. He has sensed some small part of it
>
> WESLEY: **That space and time and thought aren't the separate things they appear to be?** I just thought the formula you were using said something like that.
>
> TRAVELLER: Boy, don't ever say that again. And especially not at your age in a world that's not ready for such, such dangerous nonsense.

([TNG: Where No One Has Gone Before](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/106.htm))

Especially Kes' mention of thought as part of the equation, as well as the ability to hurl ships thousands of lightyears and the somewhat relaxed relationship with Newtonian physics got me wondering:

Did Kes become a Traveler? Did she do so completely under her own power?  A Traveler is defined as a being similar to The Traveler; a life-form with incredible super-physical powers, first encountered in ST:TNG's "Where No One Has Gone Before". In later TNG episodes he shows us his extraordinary abilities are attainable by (exceptional) humans, and eventally Wesley becomes a Traveler too ([ST:TNG "Journey's End"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Journey%27s_End_(episode))).

Comment: +1 Good question. No way is this a vote to close!

Comment: Difficult to answer without defining "Traveler". Extended canon is fairly vague, main canon more so.

Comment: @Politank-Z I've edited the question to try and define Traveler for the purpose of this question. However, your statement towards canon and the lack thereof is the very reason I'm asking here...

Comment: OK, but there is a considerable list of beings which would likely be able to duplicate The Traveler's abilities - Q, Prophets, Pagh Wraiths, maybe Metrons and Organians. Are they Travelers?

Comment: There is only so much exposition that shows can give. At some stage they have to give the audience credit and let them join the dots. Enough evidence on screen fir this to be a logical conclusion

Comment: I like the idea of this! Had never thought of it that way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would say that it is well defined what a traveller is, and it's a state of being that not just one species can attain. Once Wesley was shown how to become one, then it is open for others.

Kes most definitely seems to see things the same way and exhibits similar powers so, yes, I think it's a fair call.

From Mem-Alpha:

> He could phase out of time and dimension and move between planets and
>   starships. These abilities were based on his ability to focus the
>   energy of thoughts and in his advanced understanding of the nature of
>   reality

Pretty much the description which Kes was giving.

Comment: It **is not** well-defined what 'a Traveler' is.   That's why I say it's open to semantic debate.   The only use we have is *The Traveler*.   Is **a** Traveler anyone who can do the same thing?   Anyone from the same species?   Anyone who does ____ (what?) ?   The Traveler calls himself that because his name is unpronounceable by humans.   So it may only be his 'name' and the words 'a Traveler' are meaningless.    If 'a Traveler' means uses the same physics -- well, that's [my answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/103085/3823).

Comment: The Traveller was who he was not WHAT he was. His being was that of a level of existence which can be reached by others, so when asked if people are a traveller I take it that they mean what he was and could achieve

Comment: You're arguing a particular interpretation that is reasonable, but not explicit in canon, so ultimately an opinion.   My answer is that it depends on what the term means.   You are stating your opinion as a fact.

Comment: Actually given that there is a reasonable amount of evidence behind it, it would qualify more as a hypothesis and (within the Star Trek Universe) it is the most likely answer, of the beings presented to us.

Comment: Both birds and bats can fly, but that doesn't mean that bats are birds. Just because Kes can do X and the Traveler can, too, doesn't mean Kes is a Traveler. Is Q?

Comment: Wesley and Kes were both able to change into their final being. Q did not

Comment: @user001 Actually they did, Q states that they were corporal once 'the old era' and became what they are now 'the new era'. The Q are no different than Kes and Wesley because they started out the same. Using the same physics means nothing, why do all countries use gravity, why did they all develop spears, why do most species use warp physics - its because physics are the same for all species, so there will always be similarities - that doesn't mean one is the other

Answer (score 4):

## It depends.

The quotes you give certainly seem to **imply that the same physics** is supposed to be at work.

But what constitutes "being a Traveler" is going to be a matter of opinion and semantic argument.

In canon, we can't say much more since there's no other material.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Unlike Kes, the Traveler was, or at least appeared to be, still be a corporeal being. What happened to Kes sounds a lot more like ascension in the Stargate universe.

Comment: The Traveler could also phase in and out of reality as we knew it.  His first arrival was on a federation ship, but at the end of the episode he simply phased into a different reality, and in later episodes he appears out of nowhere.  And disappears in the same fashion.

Comment: Honestly it is pretty much Trek's ascension. Wesley is able to achieve that level of being

Answer (score 0):

I'm watching the TNG episode with the Traveller and immediately recognised the similar speech Kes made.

But without drawing any conclusions or canon crossover, it just seems like the flavour of the writers to go there. I'm also watching DS9 for the first time and can usually assign the corresponding Voyager episode.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! I'm not sure how this answers the question it just seems to be some related information of your own experiences. If you do have an answer to the question could you [edit] to clarify? Here we are a Q/A site not a discussion forum.